# How can I change multiple mp3 files name to the artists name in python?

Tags: python, properties, mp3, file-rename, mutagen

I downloaded mp3 files and a file name is like "asd.com - TheSongTitle". I want to change in order the "asd.com" to the artist name, which is given in the file properties. So I want rename multiple files.

I tried to combinate os.path... and mutagen/TinyTag but failed. I couldn't contact the files names from the os.path... to the mutagen.

Comment: You forgot to post the code you tried (as opposed to a brief description of it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.